# Cache error with Undertow

Tags: java, servlets, undertow, jboss-tools

I have a simple Servlet that overrides getLastModified.
My implementation tests some session properties and then return the lastModified or a System.currentTimeMillis().

The **servlet-api 2.5**, used by our **Jboss 4.5**, removes the millis from the lastModified before checking against the 'If-Modified-Since'. (lastModified = lastModified * 1000 / 1000).

The **servlet-api 3.1**, used by our **Wildfly**, don't remove the millis before the check.

My **Chrome 59.0.3071.86** always send the 'If-Modified-Since' without the millis, even when I return with the millis on the getLastModified.

Because of this problem my resource is not getting cached, as lastModified (non rounded) is always greater than ifModifiedSince (rounded).

So my question is, who is wrong?

- The specification changed and now I need to explicitly round the result in my
  getLastModified?
- The browser is wrongly rounding the hearder 'If-Modified-Since'?
- The new **servlet-api 3.1** should be rounding like the 2.5 does? (and I need to open a issue)

Thanks in advance.